# Using google analytics with eclipse

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am trying to use google analytics with Eclipse. I check google page

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

And their instructions are for Android studio. How can I integrate the analytics in eclipse ? I searched for how to integrate this JSON file and I can't find any hints

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only way, how to achieve this in android development for [Google analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/) no matter whether it is for ***Android Studio*** or ***Eclipse IDE***.

You can simply follow these steps in Eclipse project:

**Step 1 : Take INTERNET and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permissions.**

**Step 2 : Add "Google Play service" library project with your project.**

**Step 3 : Create an Application Class in your project, and write this code on their**

```
private Tracker mTracker;
synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
    if (mTracker == null) {
       GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
       mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
    }
    return mTracker;
}
```

**Step 4 : Add this code on your onCreate method which you want to track**

```
private Tracker mTracker;
AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
```

**Step 5 : Write this in `onResume` :**

```
mTracker.setScreenName("Page1" + name);
mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```

**Step 6 : Add configuration file in your project.**

Now run the app and check [Google analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/) in browser.

Comment: Where is the global_tracker XML file? I will get an error if I reference it without it no?  Also the biggest question is where in the project do I add the configuration file? What you said above is what google have on their website for Android studio only

Comment: You can create a folder in res with name "xml" and put global_tracker in this folder. And for the configuration file simply copy that configuration file and right click in your project and paste it, it will work.

Comment: @Snake Did you manage to implement Anlaytics in Eclipse? If yes, would you mind sharing how you did that? Where did you put your configuration file?